# Can I keep a database tunnel open for an extended period?

Tags: hana

Is it possible to keep a database tunnel active for more than 1 hour when opening it in a background process?

Comment: yes it is possible. you wan't to how? post some code first.

Comment: I'm working with SAP HCP and to connect to a database in the cloud, I first have to open a database tunnel. Once opened it will give you the database connection details. I'm opening the tunnel using the client console available in the SAP HCP sdk. I am using the command "open-db-tunnel" to open the database tunnel

Comment: ref: https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?9e3f90f2ead74229ac5c8848ed5bf292.html

Comment: when you open the tunnel you have the option to open the tunnel in a background process. When the tunnel is opened in a background process it remains open for 1 hour and then closes automatically.I was wondering if it is possible to open the tunnel for more than 1 hour when running in a background process

Answer (score 0):

The database tunnel that you create using HCP console app (neo open-db-tunnel) is meant for development and will timeout after some time. Even if run it foreground it will time out after some time. 
https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?9e3f90f2ead74229ac5c8848ed5bf292.html

For production applications use the SAP cloud connector that allows odbc and jdbc connections to HCP. 
https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?64d6a510e98941d28dbff2fc8179f175.html

What application are you connecting to HCP that you need to manually open a tunnel ?

Edit: 
Added more information as the commenter requested.